# Need help with jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery

This should be simple but is boggling me for some reason. I'm sure it's syntax thing I'm messing up.

I have a bunch of Submit buttons on a page. (It is a Survey website). Each submit button goes with a specific part of the form, so the button is disabled until until the required elements are filled out. In order to help me tie the correct submit button to the correct elements, I have the ID and NAME set to include the word "submit" plus the GUID of the question in the database. (This is an ASP.NET website). So for example, when ASP.NET renders the page, it creates this:

```
<input type="submit" id="MainContent_ctl00_submitc03d5172-f7fa-4e9c-a762-3261461befbd" value="Submit Response" name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$submitc03d5172-f7fa-4e9c-a762-3261461befbd">
```

I really just want to grab anything that has an ID (or a name) that ends with "submitc03d5172-f7fa-4e9c-a762-3261461befbd".

Bear in mind that each GUID of each button is different, so I pass the GUID to the function.

My javascript function looks like this:

```
function enableSubmit(id) {
    $('input[id$="submit" + id]').button('enable'); 
}
```

But that is not working, and I don't know why. Please help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
function enableSubmit(id) {
    $('input[id$="submit' + id + '"]').attr('disabled', false); 
}
```

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but I'm assuming it was because of the syntax error (`=` instead of `+` after `id`).

Comment: @shankarsangoli should not this be .attr('disabled', 'disabled')?

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I caught the typo, no biggie, I knew what you meant. And the button('enable') part is working fine too. I really just needed the selector to work. I was hard coding in the MainContent_ctl00_ part before and that was really ugly and in poor form, so thanks for helping me fix it.

Comment: I still didn't get the reason for down vote except for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
function enableSubmit(id) {
    $('input[id*="submit' + id + '"]').attr('disabled', false); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct geeneration of selector string would be

```
$('input[id$="submit' + id + '"]')
```

Also, from documentation, to enable jquery button after initialization (not when first creating)

```
Get or set the disabled option, after init.
//getter
var disabled = $( ".selector" ).button( "option", "disabled" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).button( "option", "disabled", true );
```

See [this jsfiddle for complete example](http://jsfiddle.net/8DnhM/2/)